# Lower bound on smallest eigenvalue of hadamard product of two Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

Let A and B be $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix. Suppose A is positive definite and denote its smallest eigenvalue as $\lambda_{\min}(A)>0$. All elements of B are positive and bounded, i.e. $0\le a <B_{ij}<b, B_{ij}=B_{ji}$. Denote the hadamard product of two matrices as $C=A\circ B$.

Here are two questions:

- Can we know whether $B$ is positive definite or not? (constant a and b can be chosen arbitrarily to satisfy the requirements)
- Can we lower bound the smallest eigenvalue of C?

P.S.
I'm encountered with this question in an engineering computation problem. The motivation is to control $-v^{\top} C v$ or $\|v^{\top} C\|$ and we can make some restrictions on B, for example, bounding the entries of $B$ or set $n$ as large as we need. I have seen some results in [On majorization and Schur products](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585901478#) while $B$ has to be positive definite, which may not be guaranteed in my question.

Comment: I don't think that there is any difference between saying "the entries of $B$ are positive" and "the entries of $B$ are positive and bounded" unless $B$ has infinitely many entries.

Comment: The answer to your first question is no. For example, if we have $a < c < d < b$, then the matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{c&d\\d&c}
$$
will never be positive definite.

Comment: One answer to your second question is that $\lambda_{\min}(C) \geq \lambda_{\min}(A)\lambda_\min(B)$.

Comment: Please note, however, that your question does not meet the standards for this site in its current form. Askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your post to address the following. Where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would also help to know a bit about your mathematical background; in particular, do you know what the Kronecker product is? Are you familiar the Cauchy interlacing theorem?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for your suggestion! (1) Actually we can suppose B has sufficiently many entries (though not infinitely). (2) Good example! So only when B is diagonally dominant can we guarantee B is positive definite? (3) I'm not sure about this inequality, does it hold even when we don't konw the postive definiteness of B? I only see a similar conclusion as Theorem 3 in [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585901478#).

Comment: Re 2: not quite; in general diagonal dominance is sufficient, but not necessary. For example, the matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{100&10\\10&2}
$$
is positive definite. Re 3: it holds in this case because the matrix $A$ is positive definite; there's a nice proof using Cauchy's interlacing inequality. I'd be happy to write that up in an answer, but I am reluctant to do so until you add the context that I mentioned due to [increased enforcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/81360) of these standards.

Comment: @BenGrossmann   (4) Encontered with this question in an engineering computation probelm. The motivation is to control the spectual property of $C$. Specifically, I want to upper bound $-v^{\top} C v$. I will try to edit my post. (5) Familiar with Kronecker product but not with the Cauchy interlacing theorem. I'm going to learn about it.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have edited my post. Thanks for your kindness and patience.

Comment: So I was wrong about the specific lower bound, but we still do have some kind of lower bound in terms of the eigenvalues. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the positivity of the entries of $B$ does not ensure that $B$ is positive definite. I further suspect that there's no good way to take advantage of the positivity of the entries in checking whether $B$ is positive definite.

Here's a proof of a corrected version of the result that I referred to

> **Claim:** If $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is symmetric with at least one negative eigenvalue, then $\lambda_{\min}(A \circ B) \geq \lambda_\max(A)\lambda_\min(B)$.

*Proof:* We note that $A \circ B$ is a principal submatrix of the Kronecker product $A \otimes B$. The eigenvalues of $A \otimes B$ are of the form $\lambda = \lambda_i(A) \lambda_j(B)$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. By the Cauchy interlacing inequality, it follows that
$$
\lambda_{\max}(A)\lambda_\min(B) = \lambda_{\min}(A \otimes B) \leq \lambda_{\max}(A \circ B). \qquad \square
$$

*Alternative proof:* Let $\mu = \lambda_{\min}(B)$, so that $B - \mu I$ is positive semidefinite. It follows that $A \circ (B - \mu I)$ is positive semidefinite, so that its minimal eigenvalue is at least $0$. Thus,
$$
\lambda_\min(A \circ B) = \lambda_\min(A \circ (B - \mu I) + \mu A)
\\ 
\geq \lambda_\min(A \circ (B - \mu I) + \lambda_\min(\mu A)
\\ =  \lambda_\min(A \circ (B - \mu I) - |\mu|\lambda_\max(A)
\\ \geq 0- |\mu|\lambda_\min(A) = \lambda_\max(A)\lambda_\min(B).
$$

Comment: Thank you! So there's no way to know whether $\mu$ is positive or the absolute value under current conditions, right? Is there any possibility to upper bound $v^{\top} C v$ or $\|v^{\top} C\|$ without knowing these?

Comment: Well, in general we can say that 
$$
\lambda_\min(A\circ B) \geq \min\{\lambda_\min(A)\lambda_\min(B),\lambda_\max(A)\lambda_\min(B)\}.
$$
Perhaps that's enough for your purposes.